# Getting CheckBox Data into a Bundle

Tags: java, android, forms, scope, bundle

I've done it before. It's not rocket science. A beautiful activity containing a perfect form. An `EditText` here... A `Spinner` there. But this time there are `CheckBox`'es.

This should be easy: setup the `onClick()` method declared in the XML, grab the ID of the view...

...thing is, I've been using a `Bundle` to gather all the data in the form together and send to my `IntentService` to drop into the SQLite database.

```
/**
 * Called when the user changes the state of any CheckBox
 * @param view  The View that was checked/unchecked  */
public void onCheckBoxChng(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    String mField = new String();
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.dlg_add_ply_chk1:
        mField = "Platinum";
        break;
    case R.id.dlg_add_ply_chk2:
        mField = "Gold";
        break;
    case R.id.dlg_add_ply_chk3:
        mField = "Silver";
        break;
    case R.id.dlg_add_ply_chk4:
        mField = "Bronze";
        break;
    case R.id.dlg_add_ply_chk5:
        mField = "HQ";
        break;
    case R.id.dlg_add_ply_chk6:
        mField = "Aurora-1";
        break;
    }
    if (checked) {
        setBundleChk(mField,1);
    } else {
        setBundleChk(mField,0);
    }
}

/**
 * Set the boolean fields in mBdlgForm based on user action on the checkboxes
 * 
 * @param   Field   The field name to change
 * @param   State   The state to set (<code>true</code> or <code>false</code> */
private void setBundleChk(String Field, int State){
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_ACTDLGADDPLYR,
                "setBundleChk(Field, State) called with: "+Field+", and "+State);
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_ACTDLGADDPLYR, "setBundleChk(): mBdlgForm Keys :");
        for (String key: mBdlgForm.keySet()){
            Log.d (Constants.TAG_FRGACTPLAYERS, "mBdlgForm."+key);
        }
    }
    if (State == 1) {
        mBdlgForm.putBoolean(Field, true);
    } else {
        mBdlgForm.putBoolean(Field, false);
    }
}
```

Piece of cake, right?

Problem is, though the `Bundle`'s scope is the entire activity, it can't been seen in the `onClick()` callback for the `CheckBox`'es NOR in any function I call from the `onClick()` callback...

...Please tell me... What am I missing?

Even after implementing "Activity.this.method()" I'm still getting the following Logcat messages:

```
    03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 12 more
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at net.clmitchell.ewtraker.pPlayers.ActDlgAddPlyr.setBundleChk(ActDlgAddPlyr.java:260)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at net.clmitchell.ewtraker.pPlayers.ActDlgAddPlyr.onCheckBoxChng(ActDlgAddPlyr.java:231)
03-04 20:09:32.349: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 15 more
```

The two line identified at the end are, respectively:

```
if (checked){ActDlgAddPlyr.this.setBundleChk(mField,1);}

for (String key: ActDlgAddPlyr.this.mBdlgForm.keySet()){
```

The following is the 2nd method:

```
    /** 
 * Set the boolean fields in mBdlgForm based on user action on the checkboxes
 * 
 * @param   Field   The field name to change
 * @param   State   The state to set (<code>true</code> or <code>false</code> */
private void setBundleChk(String Field, int State){
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_ACTDLGADDPLYR, "setBundleChk(Field, State) called with: "+Field+", and "+State);
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_ACTDLGADDPLYR, "setBundleChk(): mBdlgForm Keys :");
        for (String key: ActDlgAddPlyr.this.mBdlgForm.keySet()){
            Log.d (Constants.TAG_FRGACTPLAYERS, "mBdlgForm."+key);
        }
    }
    if(State == 1){ActDlgAddPlyr.this.mBdlgForm.putBoolean(Field, true);}
    else{ActDlgAddPlyr.this.mBdlgForm.putBoolean(Field, false);}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Valuable lessons learned:

1. It was a mistake to try and get the CheckBox data at the moment the user touched a CheckBox; I needed to trust the Android OS and gather the data AFTER the user pressed the "Save" Button using tried and true techniques.
2. Using "android:onClick" is useful in certain situations, but one must be sure when such an approach is appropriate.
3. You can use an Intent ANYWHERE in an Activity, not just to communicate with another Activity. In this case the Intent class saved my bacon: declaring a method as a listener cuts it off from nearly everything in an Activity BUT THE INTENT; I was able to grab my Activity's existing Intent, add the user input to it, then access and validate that data from where I would run the actual INSERT:

   // Grab the current Activity's Intent

   Intent iNewPlyr = getIntent();

   // Put the bundle containing user input into the Intent

   iNewPlyr.putExtras(mB);

   // process and INSERT the data from somewhere else

   validate();

I am grateful to everyone who chimed in...may all your stock options triple in value!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:-

```
Activity.this.setBundleChk(mField,1);
```

Comment: I think my real prob is with the android:onClick callback system: identifying a method in the Activity for this xml attribute seems to cut off that method from the rest of the activity, blocking me from getting data off the form and into my database...!@#$!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is a `NullPointerException` when you try to add the checked state to the `Bundle`. Have you properly initialized your `Bundle`?

Answer (score 0):

The onClick xml attribute should just work. I used it a few times without any issues.

I assume that your xml has this attribute set to `onCheckBoxChng`:

Just be sure to declare the `public void onCheckBoxChng(View view)` as a proper method of your activity  (not a static method, not a method of an inner class of you `Activity`, etc). When it is called, the `this` in your `onCheckBoxChng` method should be the `Activity` you expect, the one that hosts these `CheckBox`es.

Based on the stack-trace, it seems that your `onCheckBoxChng` is actually invoked, however, the `onCheckBoxChng` method throws an exception, which was caused by a null pointer exception in `setBundleChk`.

What code is on line 260, inside your `setBundleChk` method? If it is `String key: ActDlgAddPlyr.this.mBdlgForm.keySet()` then it looks like the `mBdlgForm` is `null`. The `mBdlgForm` `Bundle` is there, it can be 'seen'. It is just `null`. Make sure you assign a proper value to `mBdlgForm` before any onclicks are handled.